# Android set ImageView path dynamically as string

Tags: android, imageview

I have 10 images on */resources/drawable* folder as following names;
`pr1.gif`, `pr2.gif`, `... pr10.gif`
And I can easily set an image like this;
`imgview1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pr5);`

But I can't set it like following;

`int pr = getpr(dm);`
`imgview1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pr + pr);`

Is there a way to set it like this or should I use switch case?

Comment: I would recommend `switch` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the id of a drawable by name using [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String prefix = "pr";
int suffix = getpr(dm); // I assume this returns the image number

Resources res = getResources();
int resId = res.getIdentifier(prefix + suffix, "drawable", "my.package.name");
imgview1.setImageResource(resId);
```

Note you can use this for any type of resource, whether it's drawable, string, array, etc. Just make sure you change the second parameter from "drawable" to the appropriate type.